# windows batch: looping using two different lists

Tags: batch-file

I have a list of directories DIR1, DIR2 ... DIRn, each one with a single file in it: FILE1, FILE2, ... FILEn. 
I would like to launch a make on each file:

```
cd %%DIR1
make.exe %%FILE1
```

If the filename were always the same, it would be easy:

```
for %%x in (
  DIR1
  DIR2
  ...
  DIRn
) do (
  cd %%DIR1
  make.exe FILE
  rem my dirs are two levels deep
  cd ..\..
)
```

Is there a way to create a list with coupled elements so that each instance of do() selects the right one?

Comment: I see you have virtually no experience with batch-files based on your pseudo code. You will have to provide a better example then you have provided.  You said you have two lists. What is the second list?  I assume the first list is all the directories you want to process.

Comment: See `help for`, take a look at `for /L`.

Comment: Do you know in advance, the value of `n`?

Comment: As I understand it, you have not _two_ lists. You have one list of directories and you want to make _the single file_ in each of them, whatever be its name. Isn't it? `for /D %%x in (*) do (` & `cd "%%x"` & `for %%f in (*) do make.exe "%%f"` & `cd ..` & `)`

Comment: @squashman: I have no experience whatsoever with Windows batch files. On unix, I would probably created a single list concatenating the elements with a separator and used awk to get the relevant part, but in the context I have Unix is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

for %%A in (
 "DIR1|FILE1"
 "DIR2|FILE2"
 "DIRn|FILEn"
) do for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=|" %%B in ("%%~A") do (
    echo pushd "%%~B"
    echo make "%%~C"
    echo popd
)
```

Can do it using 2 `for` loops.

The `DIRn` and `FILEn` can be paired using a delimiter such as
`|` which is not used in paths. The 1st loop will get each string
paired with double quotes. The 2nd loop splits the string into
2 tokens of `DIRn` string and `FILEn` string.

Echoes in the code is for testing the output and can be replaced
with the actual commands if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually created a file EXAMPLE.TXT with text

```
DIR1 FILE1
DIR2 FILE2
...
DIRn FILEn
```

At this point,

```
for /F "eol=; tokens=1,2* " %%i in ( EXAMPLE.TXT ) do ( @echo %%i %%j )
```

runs through all line, with %%i set to DIRx and %%j to FILEx